# Toast with your android?

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to write a basic toast example based on the volume buttons getting pressed up or down. I know it sounds silly and insane since most people avoid volume button things like its the plague. I am just wondering why by chance the "Context" area would be highlighted in red.

Maybe I'm missing a code some place but either way here is something along the lines of what I am working with:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Now stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Also the code itself runs just not as it is intended to.

Comment: Can we see the whole class please, this will make it easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because context is not defined in your class/activity , Better you use

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Now stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  // if this method is inside activity
```

or

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    Toast.makeText(yourActivityname.this, "Now stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

or

Define a variable in your activity as `Context context;` intialize it in `onCreate()` Method of activity as `context = this`;
Then you can use context in  Toast.makeText method.

Comment: It's okay, I will will delete my answer since yours encapsulates more.